# Keydown event not working as same as onClick in React

Tags: reactjs, onclick, keydown

I am trying to trigger a slider next and previous events on

- **next** and **previous click** *or*
- **Left** and **Right Arrow Click**

OnClick events are working as expected. But **KeyDown handler not working as expected**.
It is working fine on first keypress, like incrementing or decrementing by 1.
But after that, it either goes to -1 or +1.

I guess, I am missing some basic concept. Pls guide me where I am missing.

You can test here:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/zen-goodall-35f17?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"

function App(){
  const [curImage, move] = useState(0);

  const handleKeypress = (e) => {
      console.log("keydown", e.keyCode);
      if (e.keyCode === 37) {
          leftClick();
      } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
          rightClick();
      }
  };

  /* eslint-disable */
  useEffect(() => {
      document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeypress);
      return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeypress);
  }, []);
  /* eslint-enable */

  function leftClick() {
    move(curImage - 1);
}

function rightClick() {
    move(curImage + 1);
}

  return(
    <>
      <button onClick={leftClick}>prev</button>
      {"   "}
      {curImage}
      {"   "}
      <button onClick={rightClick}>next</button>
    </>
  )

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use functional state update to access the previous state and `useCallback` hook for memoization so that `useEffect` won't trigger unnecessarily.

[image: Edit cocky-lake-pfg2l]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

function App() {
  const [curr, setCurr] = useState(0);

  const leftClick = useCallback(() => {
    setCurr((prevCurr) => prevCurr - 1);
  }, []);

  const rightClick = useCallback(() => {
    setCurr((prevCurr) => prevCurr + 1);
  }, []);

  const handleKeypress = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        leftClick();
      } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        rightClick();
      }
    },
    [leftClick, rightClick]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeypress);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeypress);
  }, [handleKeypress]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={leftClick}>prev</button>
      {"   "}
      {curr}
      {"   "}
      <button onClick={rightClick}>next</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with [stale closure values](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function). The solution of using useCallback hook provided by Ramesh should work for you.